# How Can We Rewrite <a href> urls using .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, url-routing

I am having `<a href>` tags on website and user go to next page with parameters added to urls depending on parameters selected from `< ahref>` . The difference in my problem is on my website when user clicks on `<a href>` url it should be rewritten to seo friendly url

**For watching it live you can see here -**

url:- **expertsusa.org/page1.php?id=4&name=Medical-Category** is not rewritten to **expertsusa.org/page1/Medical-Category** and sometimes it is successfully rewritten but shown 404 Page and weird thing is both .htaccess file and page1.php file are in same root folder of website

Example -

```
<a href="page1.php?param=4&name=Medical-Category">Medical Category</a>`
```

You can see in this paramter i am passing values through parameters. I want to rewrite this to simple seo form like below -

Url - `www.example.com/page1/Medical-Category`

**Following is the mod_rewrite Module Code in my .htaccess file**

```
ErrorDocument 404 default 
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

#RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2? [R=302,L,NE]
#RewriteRule ^(page1)/([\w-]+)/?$ $1.php?id=4&name=$2 [L,NC,QSA]


RewriteRule  ^/ViewCategories/([0-9]+)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$  ViewCategories.php?param=$1
RewriteRule    ^/Add-Expert-Listing/$1   Add-Expert-Listing.php    [NC,L]   
RewriteRule    ^/SearchResult/$1   SearchResult.php    [NC,L]    
RewriteRule    ^/Pricing/$1   Pricing.php    [NC,L]   
RewriteRule    ^/My-Lists/$1   MyLists.php    [NC,L]   
RewriteRule    ^/My-Package/$1   MyPackage.php    [NC,L]   
RewriteRule    ^/Change-Password/$1   Change-Password.php    [NC,L]   
RewriteRule    ^/faq/$1   faq.php    [NC,L]   
RewriteRule    ^/ContactUs/$1   ContactUs.php    [NC,L]   
RewriteRule    ^/ViewCategories/$1   ViewCategories.php    [NC,L]   
RewriteRule    ^/Profile/$1   Profile.php    [NC,L]   
</IfModule>
```

Comment: @PaulCrovella I have updated the question details . Is this still a duplicate of that question . Actually it rewrites url sometimes and sometimes not But when it rewrites url Page is 404 You can see comments in below answer for more details and we are discussion chat you can join there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use these rules in your site root .htaccess:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /(page1)\.php\?id=4&name=([^\s&]+)  [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2? [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteRule ^(page1)/([\w-]+)/?$ $1.php?id=4&name=$2 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: My url is here - www.expertsusa.org/page1.php?param=4&name=Medical-Category

Comment: i am using your code --------------

Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /(page1)\.php\?param=4&name=([^\s&]+)  [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2? [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteRule ^(page1)/([\w-]+)/?$ $1.php?param=4&name=$2 [L,NC,QSA]

Comment: Actually i am not having any folder structure all files are in root folder

Comment: .htaccess and page.php both are in root folder

Comment: let me get you checked . I am remove the .htaccess code and you can check page1.php on same url it will be working give 2 mins please

Comment: Now you can see the url its working 
http://expertsusa.org/page1.php?param=4&name=Medical-Category
Confirm me when you see it working

Comment: yes but url http://expertsusa.org/page1.php?id=4&name=Medical-Category is not rewritten to http://expertsusa.org/page1/Medical-Category

sorry to explain it badly but i want when i open first url it should rewritten to http://expertsusa.org/page1/Medical-Category

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108142/discussion-between-anubhava-and-steve).